# ssh: sharing control sockets over nfs

Tags: linux, ssh, nfs, connection-sharing

Can `ssh` be used with `ControlPath` set to a path on an `nfs` share if the control socket being shared was created by another host?

Attempting this gives me this error message:

```
Control socket connect(/home/user/.ssh/master-user@host:port): Connection refused
```

It works if I attempt it from the same machine.

I can't find anything in the documentation to suggest why this shouldn't be possible.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Socket files don't actually exist on the filesystem other than as a directory entry; they're only used as pointers within the VFS on the same machine. Since you can't share a VFS across multiple machines, you can't share socket files.

Comment: Great, this is the answer I was looking for. Can you also provide a reference?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have one; I may have at one time but it's long lost.